python module install stuff
whenever i try to use python module install in the shell (im trying to use the command "python -m pip install pygame") and whenever i try to it says "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases."  im not sure if im just misunderstanding this or something, but i had checked the app execution aliases thing
im on windows 10 btw
and using python 3.11 (maybe i need to update)
Error
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases
(i also tried python311 but still nothing)
i was trying to install modules and i was expecting it to work. i used "python -m pip install pygame"

What happens if you just type python? Does it produce the same error?

Please copy and paste the exact error message as text into the question. Use the <> icon to make it format as code.

@AndrewYim it wont work with out the python argument or something being there

Error Python was not found; because it's python not Python

Not pip. I’m asking whether you can run python at all, since your error message makes it look like python is the problem. I suspect that python didn’t get installed correctly. Typing python into the console should bring up a new line with >>> on the left side.

Nvm i found out what i needed to do
I just needed to update to 3.12.4

You have answered to your question, and even in your question you wrote about your intention "maybe i need to update". So, please try all your hypothesis, and then ask. This will help to keep the platform clean. Also your question is not informative at all, i.e. "python module install staff". You need to be more specific, what exactly not working.

................

as for me solution isn't to update to 3.12.4  but simply install any python because it looked like you didn't have any python.

Stop posting on this it is already solved cant you tell?
